# Three JS xhr Infinity % loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I'm currently working with ThreeJS and am admittedly a newbie with it. I can create my own models within it (basic ones) but am having issues loading an external gltf file. I am using this in a React project.

My code where I am loading the model is below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
  let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    500
  );
  camera.position.set(1, 1, 20);

  let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: false });
  renderer.setSize(500, 500);
  document.getElementById("three-canvas").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  // Load Light
  let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 1).normalize();
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  camera.position.z = 5;
  camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

  let loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    "./assets/scene.gltf",
    (gltf) => {
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
    },
    // called while loading is progressing
    function (xhr) {
      console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
      console.log(xhr.loaded, xhr.total);
      console.log(xhr);
    },
    // called when loading has errors
    function (error) {
      console.log("An error happened", error);
    }
  );
  let animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
  };
  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  animate();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div id="three-canvas"></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This file is my App.js file, located in the src directory.

The issue I'm facing is that my 3d image does not load here, and I get the attached looking screenshot instead. It's supposed to be a blue 3d car.

I also get the following in my console:

> Infinity% loaded

Which corresponds to the line of code:

```
console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + "% loaded");
```

And I also get:

> 164814 0

Which corresponds to :

```
console.log(xhr.loaded, xhr.total);
```

Which is telling me that the total is 0, but I'm not sure what that means.

I will note that if I switch my gltf file into the public directory, a completely new error occurs where I get the following in the console:

```
An error happened SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GLTFLoader.parse (GLTFLoader.js:214)
    at Object.onLoad (GLTFLoader.js:146)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (three.module.js:36370)
```

I hate to be the "Hey i'm a newbie help me" type because I've been working with javascript for a while not, but I'm pretty brand new to ThreeJS and am lost a the moment. I have been researching this and trying different solutions for about 2-3 hours now to no avail. I've gone through the docs on the threejs website, and also verified the file itself loads correctly via https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Something tells me it's either:
1) My lighting might be off, thus not showing the picture correctly
2) The file didn't load properly, hence the 0 for `xhr.total`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [here is a workaround solution, which involves explicitly assigning the total size of the model file in bytes to a variable and using that to calculate instead of `xhr.total`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75269482/infinity-loading-percentage-when-loading-gltf-model-via-xhr)